# export feature in tortoise svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using the most recent version of tortoise svn. I have checked out at code file from my small company's repository. I have made lots of changes to this code file that I have previously checked out from tortoise svn.

Now a company I am working with want me to give them the code file without the subversion hooks in it.

I know that I can use the `export` feature to remove the subversion hooks from files that are 
checked into the repository. However the code file that I am working with is not in the 
repository.

Thus can you tell me how I can remove the subversion hooks from the code file that is own 
my workstation? Do I need to check this code into a different branch of subversion and then do the export feature?

Can you tell me the best way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "without the subversion hooks"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused hooks (scripts on the server) with working copy metadata (`.svn` directory or directories if your client is 1.6.x or earlier).

If this assumption is correct, you can export from a working copy
[the redbook tells you how](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) with an example.

basically from your working copy do an 
`svn export . ~/exported-working copy`

Comment: I to not want to export from the working copy in the repository. I want to export the code that has subversion referenes in it that is on my workstation. How would I accomplish this task?

Comment: short answer: see the above answer.   Longer answer - the working copy is not in the repository.  When you checked out from the server (repository) you made a working copy on your workstation.

Answer (score -1):

Subversion hooks is nothing but a `hidden` folder created by tortoise named `.svn`.
You can manually delete these folders and you are ready with what you want.